# Calculus of variations with vector field and contour integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to use caluclus of variations to extremise the shape of a contour (closed path) in the $xy$-plane that defines an area on this planar surface, within a given region. I am having difficulty applying/adapting the typical theory, which I have learned in a context that doesn't involve contour integrals and vector fields, to this problem. I hope to get some insight on how I should proceed for this case.

**Problem description:**
In the $xy$-plane, say in the bounded region $x\in[x_{a},x_{b}], y\in[y_{a},y_{b}]$, there exists a closed contour (loop) of some shape $g(x,y)=0$ that we are free to tweak. The planar surface area enclosed by this contour is $\boldsymbol{A}=A\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}$. Now, a scalar field $W=W(x,y)$, with no variations in $z$ (i.e. $\partial/\partial z=0)$ passes through this plane and our task is to extermise the functional

$$ J(y,y_{x}):=\iint_{A} W(x,y) dx dy,$$

by finding the optimal shape for the contour $g(x,y)$ that defines the area $A$ (symbol $y_{x}$ denotes the derivative of $y$ in $x$).  One would typically expect the solution to be parameteric in form, since the shape is a closed loop within the given region. Bold symbols denote vectors.

So, to proceed with this, I faced two problems and I tried to attack them as follows (hoping to put the problem into a more familiar variational form):

(1) Needed to convert the surface integral to contour (path) integral, so that I can find the relation between $x$ and $y$ on the path, to give $g$. So, I used Stokes' theorem, by defining some vector $\boldsymbol{F}$, such that $W\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}=\nabla \times \boldsymbol{F}$, and $J$ becomes

$$J:=\iint_{A} W(x,y) dx dy\equiv\iint_{A} W\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{z}} dA=\iint_{A} (\nabla \times \boldsymbol{F})\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{z}} dA=\oint_{g}\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\boldsymbol{ds},$$

where $\oint_g$ denotes the integral around the contour [say we take $\int_{x}$ while putting $y$ according to $g(x,y)=0$ inside the integral; or we use some other parameter ($t$) for integration and continue parameterically as $x=x(t), y=y(t)$], and $\boldsymbol{ds}=ds\boldsymbol{\hat{s}}$ is the element of length along the path of the contour.

The problem faced here is: how to find $\boldsymbol{F}$ in general, in terms of the given $W$ field, to proceed?

(2) Then we can write $ds=dx\sqrt{1+(d y/d x)^{2}}=dx\sqrt{1+y_{x}^{2}}$.

But the problem here is: how do we find/write the unit vector $\boldsymbol{\hat{s}}$ along the path in terms of other variables? For example, do we say the $\boldsymbol{\hat{s}}$ is perpendicular to $\nabla g$, so that $\boldsymbol{\hat{s}}\cdot \nabla g=0$? But how can this be written down in convenient form to substitute for $\boldsymbol{\hat{s}}$ while $g$ is still general (unknown)?

How do we proceed so that we arrive at a standard variational form that allows us to then use the Euler-Lagrange equation and find $g$?

Comment: I am afraid you are having a hard time progressing with this problem because it is not well-posed. As we are free to tweak it, we can continuously deform the shape of contour so that the enclosed area decreases but the perimeter is preserved. This suggests that if a solution exists, the enclosed area will be $0$. Which makes the problem independent of the vector field $W$. So maybe you should spend more time searching for suitable hypotheses and making the problem more rigorous. (By the way, what do you mean by $\boldsymbol{A} = A\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}$)?

Comment: @Mucciolo Thanks for your advice. This comes from a problem in physics where a combination of scalar fields (here collectively called $W$) are passing through this contour loop, and we are trying to minimise the integral $\iint_{A}Wdxdy$, but the contour shape (not area) is what we can control and what was observed to make difference (because $W$ varies in $x$ and $y$ too). The trivial solution of zero area is correct, but I am looking for a nontrivial solutions, where the area is nonzero. And $\boldsymbol{A}=A\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}$ respresent the area vector, with unit normal vector along $z$.

Comment: @Mucciolo So, for the same reason you mentioned (same area can have many different contours), we are here seeking the optimal nontrivial contour (not area) that optimises the problem. Given this information, do you still think it is ill posed? Any advice on how to proceed? For example, do I need to add further contraints?

Comment: This may seem a bit subtle but, unless the enclosed area is fixed, controlling the contour shape means that we control the enclosed area too; and controlling the enclosed area means we can descrease it as much as we want. But the integral we want to minimize depends on the area, that is, we can decrease the value of the integral by decreasing the area. Not admitting the trivial solution implies the problem has no solution as we can make the value of the integral as close to zero as we want but never zero. Hence I encourage you to work the constraints.

Comment: On advices I suggest you to rule out the trivial solution with "clever" constraints and have a dummy field with an intuitive expected solution to test against the constraints every time you change them. Also you can explore symmetries and properties of the class of fields you are interested. You can ask if maybe the solution curves for these fields encloses a convex area or who knows encloses a commom shared fixed point, so you can change the origin of your coordinate system to some of them and work with polar coordinates.

Comment: @Mucciolo How about we fix the area to be constant = $A_{0}$? But the problem then is how to write down a variational integral controlled by contour shape? Basically the surface integral of the integrand (or Lagrangian, say) $W$ here is what the physics of the problem try to minimise, but I don't know how to write it down in terms of contour shape.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. You are supposed to find suitable, intuitive and reasonable constraints to the problem such that it allows you to manipulate the integral to the desired form. Them are crucial. I mean, is your problem indeed isovolumetric? Or maybe is it isoperimetric? The scalar fields you are interested can be expressed in closed-form? Try to solve the problem with a constant scalar field. Now the system is getting mad at us for extended discussion in the comment section, so I will leave you with reading suggestion.

Comment: Take a look at the following books worked examples and exercises for insights:
[1] (Brechtken-Manderscheid, U.) Introduction to the calculus of variations.
[2] (Sagan, Hans) Introduction to the calculus of variations.
(Same title, different books)
[3] (Kot, Mark) A First Course in the Calculus of Variations

Comment: @Mucciolo Yes, I have done some of such problems/texts already. And you are right that $W=0$ could be the solution for my problem above. But when can we tell if minimising the functional $\int W dxdx$ will simply be equivalent to minimising W (or putting it=0)? For example, it is well known that minimising the mean square gradient of scalar field $\phi$, as in $\int |\nabla\phi|^{2}dx$, results in Laplace's equation $\nabla^{2}\phi=0$. But we reach this conclusion by the following the usual steps of Calculus of Variations. Other classical examples cannot have $W=0$, due to $W$'s nature.

Comment: @Mucciolo ... for example, the Brachistochrome problem has $W=\sqrt{(1+y_{x}^{2})/(2g(y_{1}-y)}$ (some nonzero quantity), the Euclidean geodesic problem has $W=\sqrt{1+y_{x}^{2}}$ (nonzero), etc. These are easier to tell, because $W$ cannot be zero. But how about other problems where that is not necessarily the case?

Comment: @Mucciolo I have made some progress, changed/updated the problem and inserted constraints. But there is still an issue. See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281095/formulation-of-contour-variational-problem  Do you still think it is ill posed?

Comment: It is not that it is ill posed but it is that you will not get the answer you are looking for. To see it this consider a constant non null field $H$. You should find a huge amount of functions $g$ that are minimizers. Maybe so much that you can't even deal with them using your current tools. Also there is a thing in assuming that $y$ can be written in terms of $x$. We could move this discussion to the chat because I am also studying calculus of variations and this would benefit us both.